# Ncurses C++ print text with foreground/background colors swapped

Tags: c++, colors, ncurses

I would like to be able to print text with foreground/background colors swapped, like for example, the top bar in `nano`. But I want to use the default terminal colors. I am already calling `use_default_colors()`. Calling `pair_content(0, &c1, &c2)` just gives me `c1=-1, c2=-1`, so I don't have any values to pass in to `init_pair()`, since -1 means both default foreground and background color. How can I swap those colors in another color pair, or how can I get default foreground/background color rgb values so I can reinitialize some colors to be the default terminal foreground and background colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short: color pairs don't do that.

longer: you could apply the attribute for reverse-video **`A_REVERSE`**, but it's not a color.  It gets passed around as easily as color pairs.